# Receiving data sent from previous screen Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

**So I have two swift screen (Screen1) and Screen1Details, so my issue is to receive data sent from Screen1 to Screen1Details and pass it onto the URL that loads my JSON file.**

So far I can read that data sent from screen1 but I can't seem to be able to append it on URL that load my JSON

Here is my code

*** Screen1

```
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(fetcher.guidelines) { row in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Chapters(sentGuidelineId: row.id)){  
......

                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Some title"))
            }
        } 


*** Screen1Details
import SwiftUI
struct Chapters: View {

    let sentGuidelineId: String 
    @ObservedObject var cfetcher = ChaptersFetcher() 

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
             some code .....
        }
    }
}

struct Chapters_Previews: PreviewProvider {    static var previews: some View {
        Chapters()
    }
}


public class ChaptersFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var chapters = [Chapter]() 

    let url = URL(string: "https://myurl/api/get_screen1data.php?GuidelineId=\(sentGuidelineId)")! // My issue is here, i cant read the passed data here

    init(){ 
        load() 
    }

    func load() {  
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Chapter].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.chapters = decodedLists
                    }
                }else {
                    print("No Data found")
                }
            } catch {
                print ("Error loading data \(error)")
            }

        }.resume()

    }
}


struct Chapter: Codable, Identifiable {
    //public var error: Bool
    public var id: String
    public var name: String
    public var descriptions: String
    public var parentId: String
    public var contentLevelId: String
    public var order: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       //case error = "error"
       case id = "Id"
       case name = "ChapterName"
       case descriptions = "Descriptions"
       case parentId = "ParentId"
       case contentLevelId = "ContentLevelId"
       case order = "Order"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the func load to accept a parameter "sentGuidelineId" and call it whenever needed. I've modified your code to include a parameter for the load func and I'm calling it in the ChaptersView. Here's the code. Let me know if it helps.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var id: String = "1001"
    var body: some View {
         NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Chapters(sentGuidelineId: id)) {
                    Text("To Chapters")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Main"))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Chapters: View {
    let sentGuidelineId: String
    @ObservedObject var cfetcher = ChaptersFetcher()

    var body: some View {
        cfetcher.load(sentGuidelineId: sentGuidelineId)
        return NavigationView {
            Text("Chapters \(sentGuidelineId)")
        }
    }
}

public class ChaptersFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var chapters = [Chapter]()

    init() {
    }

    func load(sentGuidelineId: String) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://myurl/api/get_screen1data.php?GuidelineId=\(sentGuidelineId)")!
        print(url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Chapter].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.chapters = decodedLists
                    }
                }else {
                    print("No Data found")
                }
            } catch {
                print ("Error loading data \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @fellix this fixed the issues I was having

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Glad I was of help.